# extract part of field in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have log file as,

116.48.29.143 - - [01/Oct/2013:20:28:21 +0530] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 749 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"

145.89.87.211 - - [01/Oct/2013:20:28:21 +0530] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"

```
REGISTER file:/home/hadoop/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;
DEFINE EXTRACT org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.EXTRACT();             
DEFINE CustomFormatToISOorg.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.CustomFormatToISO();
DEFINE ISOToUnix org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.ISOToUnix();
DEFINE DATE_TIME org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.DATE_TIME();
DEFINE FORMAT_DT org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.FORMAT_DT();
DEFINE FORMAT org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.FORMAT();

A = LOAD 'input' USING TextLoader AS (line:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN (REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] "(.+?)" (\\S+) (\\S+) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"') ) AS (remoteAddr:chararray, remoteLogname: chararray, user: chararray,  time: chararray, request: chararray, status: int, bytes_string: chararray, referrer: chararray, browser: chararray);
```

My problem is to extract the minutes, i mean from [01/Oct/2013:20:28:21 +0530] i need to get only 28:21

how can i extract that??

Comment: Hint: there's a `STRSPLIT` UDF in the standard lib and your needed value seems to be delimited by a single space on both sides.

Comment: ok, i will try that,thak you.my overall aim is...i need to get difference between time stamps. can i do that?

Comment: If you need to get the difference, why are you dropping the dates?

Comment: i mean i need to get logs per minute..i gave sample logs, i am getting logs per every second,now i need to know the logs per second.

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to write regular expressions, so why not either modify the one you have or write a new one?  Here's a new one:

```
C = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(time, '[\\w/]+:\\d{2}([\\d:]+)\\s[+\\-]\\d{4}') AS hourMin;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a special Pig Loader for just this kind of application.
This allows for much easier parsing of Apache HTTPD logfiles.

You can use this in your pig application in a way that looks something like this:

```
REGISTER httpdlog-pigloader-1.0-SNAPSHOT-job.jar

Clicks = 
  LOAD 'access_log.gz' 
  USING nl.basjes.pig.input.apachehttpdlog.Loader(
    '%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i"',
    'IP:connection.client.host',
    'TIME.MINUTE:request.receive.time.minute',
    'HTTP.URI:request.firstline.uri',
    'STRING:request.firstline.uri.query.foo',
    'STRING:request.status.last',
    'HTTP.URI:request.referer',
    'STRING:request.referer.query.foo',
    'HTTP.USERAGENT:request.user-agent')
  AS ( 
    ConnectionClientHost,
    RequestReceiveTimeMinute,
    RequestFirstlineUri,
    RequestFirstlineUriQueryFoo,
    RequestStatusLast,
    RequestReferer,
    RequestRefererQueryFoo,
    RequestUseragent);
```

You can download it here: https://github.com/nielsbasjes/logparser